# How may I filter lines in Apache Pig?

Tags: filter, apache-pig, lines

I have a txt, and then I loaded lines from the txt, with this script:

```
lines = LOAD '/user/hadoop/HDFS_File.txt' AS (line:chararray);
```

I need to filter every lines, with some words. I mean:

if the line is:

```
'Hi, I'm lord Stark, how are you?'
```

I need to search: `"how are you"` in the line, for every line in a txt and count the occurrences.

I tried with:

```
sentences = FOREACH lines GENERATE (FILTER lines BY (f1 matches 'how are you')) AS sent;
```

But it doesn't work. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following to filter the records having "how are you" string:

```
lines = LOAD '/user/hadoop/HDFS_File.txt' AS (line:chararray);
sentence  = FILTER lines BY (line matches '.*how are you.*');
```

To get the count of occurence:

```
grouped= GROUP sentence ALL;
sentence_COUNT = FOREACH grouped GENERATE COUNT(sentence);
```